# Lossless Bitmap rotation in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm making a top-down Racing game in a forms application (I know it's EXTREMELY ineffective, but it's a school project and teacher says forms app only). I have a car Bitmap and want to rotate it by x degrees. I have found a method that does that exactly but my problem is that after a few rotations the bitmap starts getting very blurry and impacts performance heavily.
Is there a way to make this algorithm more effective and not loose quality exponentially?

Here's the rotation method:

```
public Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, PointF offset, float angle)
{
    float sin = (float)Math.Abs(Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI / 180.0));
    float cos = (float)Math.Abs(Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI / 180.0));
    float ImgWidth = sin * bmp.Height + cos * bmp.Width;
    float ImgHeight = sin * bmp.Width + cos * bmp.Height;
    Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap((int)ImgWidth,(int) ImgHeight);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);
    g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);
    g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));
    return rotatedBmp;
}
```

Comment: use the same Bitmap and Graphics object each time this function runs

Comment: Always start by passing in the original image. Alternatively, it might be worthwhile to just create a bunch of images rotated at different angles in a decent graphics package, clean them up as needed and import them into your application instead of trying to rotate a single bitmap. You could still potentially use rotation for "in-between" angles if really necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overwrite your original source image after it has been rotated.

Store your angle as absolute, not as an offset from the last game frame.

Finally, rotate your original source image from scratch each frame, then draw the result.

The only lossless rotations are rotations of a multiple of 90 degrees. Lossless rotations are not possible at any other angle.

**EDIT**

Also, it's not necessary to keep an intermediate copy of the rotated image in it's own buffer. You can just draw the rotated car directly to the screen.

If I'm wrong, and you absolutely need the rotated image of the car buffered, you can just calculate the maximum size you will need for the rotated image and reuse the buffer. You can do that by calculating the diagonal image size and using it for width *and* height, and then draw the car centered in that new buffer.

Something like this: (untested)

```
        double maxSize = Math.Sqrt(bmpCp.Width * bmpCp.Width + bmpCp.Height * bmpCp.Height);
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap((int)maxSize, (int)maxSize, pf);

        //...

        gBmp.DrawImage(bmpCp, new PointF((maxSize - bmpCp.Width) / 2.0,
                                         (maxSize - bmpCp.Height) / 2.0));
```

Comment: I have done what you suggested, but now it cuts the top and the right side of my bitmap when it's pointed "downwards". Here's the modified class: http://pastebin.com/C8dsrcV1

Comment: I think you may be miscalculating the size of the canvas for the rotated image, but I wouldn't recommend doing that anyways. You don't need an intermediate copy of the rotated image in it's own buffer, you can just draw the rotated car directly to the screen. If I'm wrong, and you absolutely need the buffered image, you can just calculate the maximum size you will need for the rotated image and reuse the buffer. Details will been added to my answer.